# LaTeX: How to get the following output in table?

Tags: tables

I am writing a research document in which I need to merge two columns, I did the code for it but not getting desired output, Can anyone please tell me ? what's wrong in my code....

[image]

here is my latex code

```
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
  \hline
  Image Name & 1 & 2 & 4 & 5 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{9}\\
  \hline
  &  &   &   &   &  & M  & D  & X  & Y \\
  \hline
  ..............
  ..............
  ..............
  ..............
  ..............

  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Your post was migrated here from another Stack Exchange site. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of saying

```
... \multicolumn{2}{c}{8} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{9}
```

you need to say

```
... \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{8} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{9}
```